# How to ensure ordered processing of events using spark streaming?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-storm, amazon-kinesis

I have a use-case where I want to process a large number of events. These events contain multiple attributes in them. However, I want to ensure that for a given attribute(key), there is not more than 1 spark execution running at a given time because if two executions run in parallel for the same key, the end result will be determined by a race condition.

My model is something like:

- Receive a change event from some system.
- Enrich the event using attributes in my local database.
- Send the enrich event to spark streaming using Kinesis.
- Update the local database with the output.

Is apace-storm a better contender for such a system?

Comment: The basic idea is that two records with same key should not processed concurrently. Example: If key is username, then for any user X, if there are two events E1 and E2, then E2 gets processed once E1 is done.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon Kinesis uses shards in the stream as data containers. And inside a shard, it is guaranteed that the values are processed sequentially.

You can exploit this feature for your use case: So use predefined "**Partition Key**" values while putting records in the stream.

For example, if you are dealing with user values, you can use the id for a user's event as partition key on the **producer side**.

- User #1: First makes purchase, then updates score, after that browses to page X etc.
- User #2: First does X, then does Y, after that Z event occurs etc.

That way, you'll be sure that the events for a single user will be processed in a timely manner. And you'll have your parallelism for different user's events (i.e. Kinesis Records).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Just one clarification. I understand spark attaches 1 D-Stream to each shard of Kinesis. However, does this also mean that for 2 records in a single shard X, Y..  Y will only be processed once the processing for X is complete? Or does it just mean that first X will be picked then Y but they can be in processing stage at the same time?

Comment: If you place X first, than Y in the same shard; yes X will be processed first, then Y will. They cannot be processed at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

You can have just one partition and by that stop parallelism.

Also from my opinion, for scenario like this Apache kafka is a better choice.

Comment: The objective is not to stop parallelism and lose performance. The objective is to control parallelism at a key level or shard level if you say.